# How to reverse hashed and salted password ?

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

I am using vBulletin and the login uses this to cross-refer to the database.

```
md5(md5($pass).$salt)
```

How do i make a PHP script such that every password input will automatically be hashed and salted as well so that it is able to authenticate with the vBulletin database ?

Comment: you can compare the hashed input with the field in the db instead of reversing md5()...impossible...also i strongly advice you not to use md5() for passwords while it is broken..cracked and full of vulnerabilities...

Answer (score 5):

Because hashing is not encrypting, hashes can't be reversed.

If you want to be able to reverse passwords, you have to use an encryption function.

Answer (score 4):

> How to reverse hashed and salted password ?

Hashing is a one-way process. i.e. If you pass a string you get a hash which cannot be reversed., It can be used for comparison purposes.

Some of the hashing algorithms are `md5()`[not considered secure] , `sha-1`, `sha-256`

### Best Hashing as of now...

Make use of [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) coupled with some strong salt. If you have PHP 5.5 , then you can very well make use of [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Then what should i do so that the password that is being input gets hashed and salted as well ?

Comment: apply the hashing algorithm you've just mentioned on the input...

Answer (score -1):

Just use the code you posted. Get the form data and wrap it in the appropriate md5() function.

Comment: Lets to say my password is $password . How do wrap it ? I'm new sorry .

Comment: @user3132112 Just to clarify you're doing this to compare two password hashes? Just FYI you can't reverse a hash to get the plain password. Anyway you'd just do md5(md5($password).$salt) like in your post above using the same $salt value as your vBulletin forum. Compare the result against the hashed vBulletin password and you'll be able to verify if they're the same or not.

Comment: Yeap . If my current code is  $password=$_POST['password'];    how do i apply md5(md5($password).$salt   into it ?

Comment: @user3132112 Exactly that. You will need to know the correct $salt value though. You can just use md5($password) as a demonstration of showing how to hash a password, but if vBulletin uses a specific salt value then you'll need that if you hope to compare passwords.